# Два селектора на одном уровне DOM, jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

Корректна ли данная запись выборки?; чтобы здесь выполнилось логическое И:
Нужно выбрать элементы на странице с id="size7" и id="size8".

```js
else if ($('#size7' + '#size8').is(':checked')) {
  $('#type1').addClass('increase');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: а что в итоге должно быть выбрано?

Answer (score 1):

Мультиселекторы должны разделяться запятыми:

```js
if ($('#size7,' + '#size8').is(':checked')) {
    $('#type1').addClass('increase');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[**Источник**](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

В вашем же примере для одновременной проверки двух чекбоксов придется писать два условия:

```
if ($('#size7').is(':checked') && $('#size8').is(':checked')) {
    $('#type1').addClass('increase');
}
```